# Retrieving all titles for each category using php

Tags: php, mysql

Please can anyone suggest how I can go about achieving this in php I have two tables categories and article. The categories table has two fields id and names
article table contains id category_id title. One category can be tie to many article title in the article table. Please how can I retrieve all titles belonging to each categories in my article table without using the get variable.
The below code is retrieving just each categories but not pulling the article titles for each
    Categories Class

```
public static function find_all_categoryid() {
  return self::find_by_sql("SELECT a.title, b.names,  b.id FROM article a LEFT OUTER JOIN article_categories b ON a.category_id=b.id GROUP BY a.category_id");
}
```

Index Page

```
<?php $cats = Categories::find_all_categoryid(); ?>
<?php foreach($cats as $cat): ?>
       <h4><?php echo $cat->names; ?></h4>
       <p><?php echo $cat->title; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

can anyone please assist. Thank you